# Applying custom plugins using PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I've downloaded the [select within](https://github.com/HeikkiVesanto/SelectWithin) plugin to select features inside polygons objects. I've imported the plugin using `import SelectWithin as sw` in the console but QGIS does not suggest any of its methods to use.

How can I apply this plugin to my script using PyQGIS and is it possible to use the functions of this plugin in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show *Select Within* window using this script:

```
from SelectWithin.select_within import SelectWithin

# 1st SelectWithin is plugin name, 2nd select_within is module/file name,
# 3rd SelectWithin is class name within the select_within.py file

sw = SelectWithin(iface)
sw.run()
```

[image]

Also, you can use `count_vertices`, `create_centroids`, `centroid_point`, `dissolve_feats` methods with varible `sw`, but cannot run processes which `OK` button does, without displaying *Select Within* window. Because many of processes are called in `run` method, and that method always displays the window.

If you want to use all functionality  of the plugin, you need to change the contents of `select_within.py` file (especially `run` method).